# UWP add MenuFlyout(Item) dynamically to an existing menuflyout

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, flyout

A `Grid` in my `DataTemplate` currently has this `Flyout`.

```
                    <Grid.ContextFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout x:Name="AlbumFlyout">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Shuffle" Text="Shuffle" />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </Grid.ContextFlyout>
```

And I also have a `Flyout` generated dynamically:

```
    public static MenuFlyout GetAddToPlaylistFlyout()
    {
        MenuFlyout flyout = new MenuFlyout();
        flyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem()
        {
            Icon = new FontIcon() { Glyph = "\uEC4F" },
            Text = "Now Playing"
        });
        flyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutSeparator());
        flyout.Items.Add(new MenuFlyoutItem()
        {
            Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Add),
            Text = "New Playlist"
        });
        foreach (var playlist in Settings.settings.Playlists)
        {
            var item = new MenuFlyoutItem()
            {
                Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Audio),
                Text = playlist.Name
            };
            flyout.Items.Add(item);
        }
        return flyout;
    }
```

It is dynamically generated because I need to reuse it a lot and some of its `MenuFlyoutItem` is generated from user's data.

How can I insert the code-generated `Flyout` right below the `Shuffle` above the `Delete`?

---Update---

This is part of my `ListView` definition.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="SongsListView"
    Grid.Row="1"
    AllowDrop="True"
    CanDrag="True"
    CanReorderItems="True"
    ContainerContentChanging="SongsListView_ContainerContentChanging"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="SongsListView_ItemClick"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Songs, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ReorderMode="Enabled"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemContextFlyout}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two fixed items, `Shuffle` and `Delete`.

You want to insert the newly generated MenuFlyout item between these two items. Try this code:

```cs
var newFlyout = GetAddToPlaylistFlyout();
foreach(var item in newFlyout.Items)
{
    AlbumFlyout.Items.Insert(AlbumFlyout.Items.Count - 1, item);
}
```

By the way, if your `AlbumFlyout` is in the `DataTemplate` and may not be available in Code-behind, you can try to put it in `Page.Resources` and then reference it with `StaticResource`.

Best regards.

Comment: Do you mean put the `DataTemplate` in the resources?

Comment: It is not required to put the DataTemplate in the Resource, but if your `MenuFlyout` is a child of the DataTemplate, you can consider putting the MenuFlyout in the Resource in order to get it.

Comment: I have now put the `MenuFlyout` in the `Resource` and assign the `MenuFlyout ` using `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` but now I have another problem. I used to be able access the data bound to the DataTemplate by doing `(sender as MenuFlyoutItem).DataContext`. Now it's returning `null`. How can I get the data?

Comment: Try using ContextFlyout="{StaticResource your_flyout}" so that MenuFlyout can share the DataContext

Comment: Yes this is what I did: `<Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemContextFlyout}" />` but I still get null. I put it in the Style of `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: Please do not write ContextFlyout to Style, complete resource link in DataTemplate.

Comment: I have actually also has a question with that. For example, my `DataTemplate` has a `Grid` as it content. And should I register the `MenuFlyout` to `Grid.ContextFlyout`? But the problem with that is the right click only triggers the flyout when I click on the place with UI element on the `ListViewItem`. Adding it to the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` makes it work everywhere.

Comment: You can create a highly transparent color as the Grid background so that the mouse doesn't penetrate the Grid, and you can also set the ListViewItem's `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to **Stretch** to ensure that the Grid can fill the entire element.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions but can you take a look at my code [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml) why right click doesn't trigger the `MenuFlyout`?

Comment: When right-clicking on an actual element (such as a TextBlock), will MenuFlyout appear? If so, the problem is that on your transparent background, you have not set the Background for the Grid, which means that when you right click on the blank, the pointer actually penetrates the Grid, and there is no actual trigger, you can try to give the Grid set the Background and observe the trigger.

Comment: Do you mean I need to create an transparent element to be the background or just set it to be transparent?

Comment: Please set the background color of the Grid, do not be transparent. You can create a SolidColorBrush resource and set Opacity to 0.1, but don't be transparent.